# do active directory groups have any type of "enabled" or "deleted" indicator?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Do Active Directory groups have any type of "Enabled" or "Deleted" indicator? The UserPrincipal object has an "Enabled" property but I didn't find a similar property for the GroupPrincipal object.

Comment: There are `isDeleted` and `isRecycled` attribute which you'd like to check!

Comment: the following code did not appear to detect the existence of isDeleted/isRecycled attributes: var directoryEntry = adGroup.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
var isDeleted = directoryEntry.Properties["isDeleted"].Value;
var isRecycled = directoryEntry.Properties["isRecycled"].Value;